# flex vs silverlight for student

Tags: apache-flex, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, flex3

I am a student of computer science and am interested in learning development of RIAs. So which among silverlight and flex is more suitable for me and y?

Comment: I think that you'll need to tell us a bit more about your programming background before we can answer that.

Comment: among programming languages i know C, C++, core Java. I am also familiar with flash and HTML

Comment: It might also help you have a specific target in mind and how far into the future you need to be looking.  Flex, Silverlight and HTML5 each carve up the problem area differently, so knowing where in the hole RIA space you want to be would help?  You want to create immesive experiences for public vistors on the web?  You want to create more engaging Line-of-business apps?  You want to deliver good moblie web experiences?  You want to learn skills that are more future than now?

Comment: i would recommend you to learn Silverlight and C# later on you can use it for much more than just RIA , also WPF almost identical to silverlight so you wont have to learn tons of new stuff to develop desktop apps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex with ActionScript is better than Silverlight. You can find a range of tutorials and application for Flex in the web.

HTML 5 has come, but still you will find a range of browsers not supporting it fully. You may end up frustrated with most of your clients in I.E 6.0

**My Bet is**

Flex with PHP OR
Flex with JAVA

Could really enhance your programming skills and career growth to a peak.

Comment: "Flex with ActionScript is better than Silverlight" Better for what? Based on what? Elaboration is key, without it turns your the majority of your answer into an opinion.

Comment: Really? Flex by itself may be "better", but Actionscript clearly isn't. In my experience AS3 is a bad language which clearly shows its age - unpredictable behavior (e.g. for..in loops on objects), inconsistent API crossing over into procedural stuff several times, fail-silently in the run-time environment and very limited library support (e.g. XSD validation). At work I must work with AS3 and I would give my left leg to be able to use Java 6 or C#3/4. Sure, you can do some nifty functional stuff with AS3 (mixins, currying, ...) but that doesn't justify the gaping holes in the language.

Comment: @Daniel and @Baelnorn: Flex and AS3 is far better than siverlight and html5 by comparing the results in products created with such tech. If you did not learned enough AS3 or flex because you are still into c# mirage then please do not say AS3 is a bad language. Each language has it's pros. and cons. and of you manage to deal with them you will find that the important thing is the result of your work and not so much the design pattern you have used or how easy you add a line of code with just one button click in the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight is the very accessible.  You can develop Silverlight applications using free tooling provided by Microsoft in via its  "Express" range of tools.   Also if you use C# as part of your work you'll be learning a language which has wider uses.  ActionScript on the other will teach quite a few aspects of Javascript yet it also has many features that are perculiar to its slant of Javascript and only really useful in the flex context.

However have you considered HTML5 as a platform for RIA?  Whilst being embyronic and almost non-existant tooling it may also be a contender for RIA delivery in the furture.

Comment: What features of ActionScript are peculiar and/or only useful in the Flex context?

Comment: +1 for considering HTML5. -1 for Silverlight over Flex. Silverlight will be a casualty to HTML5 before Flash is.

Comment: @adamcodes:  Well it is very much horses for courses.  However I can't see flash being used much for inhouse corporate LOB work and corporates tend to really drag their feet when it comes to browser installs.  Whereas Silverlight is growing in strength in this area.  Silverlight is the basis for development on WP7 it remains to be seen if it can rival iPhone or even Android.  In other words Flash and HTML5 will be going head to head in an identical space, whereas Silverlight has one or two other niches it has carved out for itself.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think you'd be silly to ignore Silverlight. It's going from strength to strength and is growing a lot faster than Flash. As Anthony rightly points out, businesses that would never have considered Flash are turning to Silverlight for replacing both Web and Desktop apps.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that flash+flex is much better than html5 (which is too slow for now) and silverlight (which was a big disapointment for me, a big BUM at the launch and that's all)

Check out http://flex.org/ for some nice RIA tools, and maybe that can help you more in taking your decision.

Comment: Also Check out https://freeriatools.adobe.com/ where students can request free copies of Flash Builder; Adobe's IDE for building Flex applications.